# When to use Regexp.new()?

Tags: ruby, regex

I couldn't find any proper answer as Regexp stands for Regular Expressions. Here is an example:

```
test = Regexp.new("Hello")
```

It returns `/Hello/`, but I'm confused over the use of this. Why not use `/Hello/` directly? Can anyone give me a small example of `Regexp.new()` function?

Comment: How did you google it - there are a lot of resources: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: Have you tried reading the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-c-new)? It provides few examples.

Comment: @toro2k thanks I read it but still confused. We can use /Hello/ as a regular expression why use Regexp.new()?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, I'm familiar with Regular Expression but my question is, in what situation I should use REgexp.new()?

Comment: @Amession - Ah, now I get you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's imagine you want to make your system detect "a sentence that starts with DOG and ends with CAT". Obvious Regex would be something like `/DOG.+CAT\./`[1].

So far, works. But now you'd like to be able to enhance the system, so the user can configure the opening and closing words. You might be able to do it with `//` syntax and interpolation:

```
/#{startWord}.+#{endWord}\./
```

but you also can do it with simple strings:

```
Regex.new(startWord + ".+" + endWord + "\.")
```

Cosmetics. Use what you like the most. However, there is **one more thing** that's important. With the `new` function, you can pass not only one, but also **more parameters**. See [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-new).

So, the main[2] purpose of the existence of `new` from your point is actually being able to pass more arguments than just one. With `//` you can only pass the regex-formula[3]. With `new` you can pass options.

Few details were oversimplified for clarity.
[1] It is not a valid "sentence detector". It is only some regex to show the problem.
[2] It's not main purpose. The `new` is a **constructor**. It must exist or we would not be able to construct the object. Actually, the `/blargh/` syntax is translated into a `new` call.
[3] Actually, with `//` you can pass some options too, like `/CaSEiNseNsiTive/i`. But, well, constructors are still more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have a variable with a string which you want to reuse in a regular expression:

```
a_string = "I want to match this"
```

You can then easily create a regex using:

```
Regexp.new(a_string)
```

Comment: So it is similar to: 

Regexp.new("I want to match this")

right?

Comment: It is but you can imagine a situation where you want to build a regex with a string which you don't have direct control over, e.g. user's input. Or you can use it to iterate over a collection of strings to create a number of regexes and match them against something.

Comment: It is also possible to interpolate the string into the regular expression literal: `/#{a_string}/`.

Comment: So what the hell happens when I use that function? Does it return if it found a string matching the regex, or does it just hand you off a string?

Answer (score 3):

All constructor features are accessible to the literals. Actually, literals allow you to specify even *more* options than `new`:

```
# Supported by Regexp.new

/regexp/m  =>  Regexp::MULTILINE
/regexp/i  =>  Regexp::IGNORECASE
/regexp/x  =>  Regexp::EXTENDED
/regexp/n  =>  Regexp::NOENCODING

# Apparently only available to literals

/regexp/u  =>  UTF-8
/regexp/s  =>  Windows-31J
/regexp/e  =>  EUC-JP
/regexp/o  =>  Interpolate only once; only makes sense in literals
```

Why are there many encoding options? The reason is that regular expression objects created via literals assume the encoding of the source code; the encoding options exist to force a specific encoding. The constructor lets you pass in an arbitrary string whose encoding you can explicitly control.

The `new` method is very useful when the regular expression is of dynamic nature. While it is possible to interpolate strings into the literal:

```
string = '.+'
regexp = /#{string}/
```

It is not possible to interpolate options into the literal. There is nothing like this:

```
options = 'ui'
regexp = /.+/#{options}
```

Using the constructor here is advantageous because it lets you decide which options to pass in dynamically. If you were to make a program that lets users create their own regular expressions via a graphical user interface, it would be natural to create regular expressions using `Regexp.new`.